# horizontal scrollview with 3 options on screen

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I need to display categories as shown in image.[image]

It should scroll horizontally and also get event when category come to the middle.

I require it without viewpager.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use following layout may be it is useful for your application

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/hsv" android:background="@null"        android:visibility="visible" android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@null" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Textview android:id="@+id/about" android:text="POPULARITY" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
        <Textview android:id="@+id/color"
            android:clickable="true" android:text="NEW ARRIVAL" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
        <Textview android:id="@+id/kids"  android:text="DISCOUNTED"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="POPULARITY"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="NEW ARRIVAL"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="DISCOUNTED"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="LOW PRICE"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="LOW PRICE"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

You can use this for horizontal scrolling.

Also have a look at this - http://viewpagerindicator.com/